# MySQL Server + phpMyadmin on Ubuntu Server 20.04 from google cloud platform, where to start?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am a new starter for google cloud platform, I started a thing on marketplace which I think will help me install craft-cms, how to start? I mean where can I have the password of the root user on mysql, where is the password of phpadmin, I don't know where to start [error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBvI5.png)

[deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8PC.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the installation of MySQL after deploying the solution. You can't login to phpMyAdmin because you have not set up a password for root yet.

I assume you deployed the solution
[MySQL Server + phpMyadmin on Ubuntu Server 20.04](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/cloud-infrastructure-services/mysql-ubuntu2004) and now you have a VM that you can SSH into.

1. SSH into the VM machine.
2. run the command `sudo mysql_secure_installation` to start the MySQL configuration.
3. Follow the onscreen prompts and reply 'y' to the prompts.
4. run the following commands to set up a password for root. Be sure to replace 'your_pass_here' with your own password.

```
    sudo mysql
    
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_pass_here';
    
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

5. Now you can log off your SSH session and login to phpMyAdmin using your new password.

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed one of the marketplace solutions, you will have a deployment manifest in the Deployment Manager section of the Google cloud console.

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform
   https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Ensure that you have the correct project selected (that will be the
   one you deploy the marketplace solution in the first place) in the
   dropdown menu in the top of the screen.
3. In the search bar type Deployment Manager and select "Google Cloud
   Deployment Manager".
4. Press the button "Go To Cloud Deployment Manager"
5. You will find listed all the deployments for that project. You
   should be able to find your deployment there.
6. Click on the deployment name and in the next screen you will be able
   to find the deployment specifications, usually you will find the
   names and passwords for the deployment there.

Here is an example of a deployment as seen in the Deployment Manager:

[image]